# Reuse Entity Framework Select Passing a bool Func to Select

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-6

I have the following code i would like to reuse in few places in my code and the only thing that keeps changing is the `IsChecked`,I'm looking for a way to pass along the expression to the select (just like i always do with the Where)

```
    public static List<Customer> ReusableFunctionToGetCustomers(dbContext context, Expression<Func<Customer,bool>> CheckedPredicate)
    {
        return context.Customers.Where(/* complex reused code*/)
            .Select(c => new CustomerVM
            {
                Id = c.CustomerId,
                Name = c.Name,
                IsChecked = true/*somehow use the CheckedPredicate Expression */,
            }).OrderBy(t => t.Name).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: that means you want to pass expression as a parameter that to be execute after where

Comment: within the select for the IsChecked property

Comment: not the Where i Need to pass the CheckedPredicate  to the IsChecked  in the Select

Comment: yes but you are setting Is-checked = true in select block

Comment: correct but i want to put the CheckedPredicate, as the comment says

Comment: go through this article  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493917/Dynamic-Querying-with-LINQ-to-Entities-and-Express

Comment: this article is not helpful

Comment: I think you're going to run into problems the way you're trying to do it. I had a quick play around with `IsChecked = CheckedPredicate(c)` using a `Func<Customer, bool>` and got a `System.NotSupportedException` exception - `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities`. I suspect you're going to run into similar issues even with Expressions (but I could be wrong).

Comment: yup i had the same issue